# Can TCP/UDP sockets and Websockets communicate with each other?

Tags: sockets, websocket, socketserver, tcpsocket

I have been going through this websockets [article.](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/)

Can a web-socket communicate with a TCP/UDP Socket and viceversa?

Answer (score 4):

Websockets use TCP sockets.
Websockets are a higher level technology relying on TCP sockets, exactly the same way HTTP is transported over TCP sockets.
In fact, Websockets are a special extension of HTTP. The client issues a special HTTP request that leaves the underlying TCP socket open, which then allows both the client and the server to push data on the connection.

Comment: But a 'legacy' socket communicate with a Websocket? Can i open a legacy socket server in python and let a websocket communicate with it?

Comment: A TCP socket is just a raw connection. Websockets is a higher level protocol like HTTP. It's like asking if HTTP can communicate with TCP. Of course it can, because the data in HTTP/Websocket is transported over a TCP connection, however you will need to write a client/server to handle the Websocket/HTTP protocol data.

Answer (score 1):

What you essentially need is a WebSockets client library in your application. This will utilise TCP sockets on a lower level, and talk to your webserver using the WebSockets protocol.

The benefit of this approach is that your application code only has to deal with the library's higher-level API as well, instead of the nitty-gritty sockets API, where you'll have to implement HTTP and/or WebSockets again.